# Erro em rbind: "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi))"

Tags: r, funções

Estou tentando construir uma função que conte o número de casos completos em arquivos .csv (data frames), ou seja, o número de linhas com valores (e não "NA"). A função que escrevi consegue ler o(s) arquivo(s) especificados na chamada da função e contar o número de linhas com casos completos, mas preciso retornar essa informação como um data frame, com 2 colunas, "id" para a identificação do arquivo (são todos identificados com números) e "Nobs" para o número de observações (os casos completos). Nessa função, o meu loop de leitura não consegue depois armazenar os resultados da contagem nesse data frame. A figura mais abaixo tem alguns exemplos do que a função deveria retornar.

A função é essa:

```
completeF<-function(directory,id) {

#set file location
address<-paste(getwd(), directory, sep="/")

#Creates objects for later results keeping
Completev<-data.frame(matrix(0,1,ncol=2))
temp<-data.frame(matrix(0,1,ncol=2))
#colnames(Completev)<-c("id","Nobs")
#colnames(temp)<-c("id","Nobs")

#read files
files <- dir(directory)

for (i in id){
    #read files
    each.file<-read.csv(paste(address,files[i],sep="/"),h=TRUE)

    #count complete cases: count number of lines with values for sulfate and nitrate
    obs<-na.omit(each.file)
    rowcount <- nrow(obs)

    #keep results in temporary data frame, and then the final one
    temp<-cbind(i,rowcount)
    Completev<-rbind(Completev,temp)
}
colnames(Completev)<-c("id","Nobs")
return(Completev)
```

}

[image: Estes são exemplos do resultado que a função deveria retornar]

Mas o que obtenho é

```
> completeF("specdata",1:5)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Executando o Traceback, entendi que o erro ocorre aqui: Completev<-rbind(Completev,temp), **com o rbind**, mas não entendo por que! Nem fixando antes os nomes das colunas, antes do loop "for", resolve.

O que poderia estar errado no loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está reatribuindo a variável `temp` a cada iteração e apagando o nome das colunas.

Uma opção é copiar o nome das colunas a cada iteração:

```
temp<-data.frame(i,rowcount) # nova data frame com seus próprios nomes
names(temp) <- names(Completev) 
Completev<-rbind(Completev,temp)
```

Você também pode criar uma nova data frame já com os nomes a cada interação:

```
Completev<-rbind(Completev,data.frame(id=i,Nobs=rowcont)
```

Veja porém que em termos de *performance* essa não é uma boa solução, é muito mais eficiente pré-alocar um vetor e construir a `data.frame` de uma única vez (veja [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689650/how-to-append-rows-to-an-r-data-frame) para alguns *benchmarks*).

Comment: Isso funcionou, Anthony! Obrigada!

Comment: Olá Leila, é um prazer ajudar. Aqui no Stack Overflow você pode indicar que uma resposta é boa ou ruim votando nela (com a setinha para cima ou a setinha para baixo). Se uma resposta resolveu seu problema você pode também aceitá-la (simbolo verde de "correto" embaixo dos votos). Com essas sinalizações você ajuda outras pessoas que esbarrem em problemas semelhantes.

Comment: Anthony, tentei votar, mas preciso ter 15 pontos de reputação... mas já aceitei sua resposta. :^)

Comment: Sem problemas Leila, obrigado.